# Does factoring by sum and difference of cube or sum and difference of squares yield the same answer

Tags: factoring

Q) Factor: $s^6-1$

If I start by doing sum of difference of squares I get

$(s^3)^2 - (1)^2$

$(s^3-1)(s^3+1)$

$(s+1)(s^2-s+1)(s-1)(s^2+s+1)$

If I start by doing sum or difference of cubes I get

$S^6 - 1$

$(s^2)^3 - (1)^3$

$(s^2 - 1) (s^4+s^2 + 1)$

ANS: $(s-1)(s+1) (s^4+s^2 + 1)$

Both the answers are different, as a matter of fact I know that when I started by doing the sum or difference of square method, the answer I got was correct , but what am I doing wrong in the 2nd method then?

Comment: because $s^4+s^2+1$ is still factorable.

Answer (score 2):

$s^4+s^2+1=(s^2-s+1)(s^2+s+1)$ so it is the same answer.

The way to complete the factoring is:

$s^4+s^2+1=s^4+2s^2+1-s^2=(s^2+1)^2-s^2=(s^2-s+1)(s^2+s+1)$

Comment: How were you able to factor this though.

Comment: I explained to you already. What exactly is not clear?

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry, i honestly didn't see the explanation, Thank You!